# Uploading and displaying mulitple Images with Java script - wont recognize previous images unless uploaded at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this Jquery code(see below) that allows the user to open a file browser and select multiple images, they then get displayed for the user to view, after which they can save them to the database but there is a problem, when you select multiple images all at once and then open them it displays fine and saves all the images to the database.

However when you select one and then click open, click browse again upload another image and so on they get displayed fine, but when the user saves them only the most recently selected image gets saved to the database, I would like to be able to select and open one at a time and then still save them all to the Database at once.

Thanks in advance! Heres the code:

`<input type="file" name="files" value="" id="upload-image" multiple="multiple"/>
    <div id="thumbnail"></div><br />`

```
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");
    console.log(fileInput);
    fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        var files = this.files
        showThumbnail(files)
    }, false)

    fileDiv.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false)

    fileDiv.addEventListener("dragenter", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    fileDiv.addEventListener("dragover", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);

    fileDiv.addEventListener("drop", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        var dt = e.dataTransfer;
        var files = dt.files;

        showThumbnail(files)
    }, false);

    function showThumbnail(files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i]
            var imageType = /image.*/
            if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {
                console.log("Not an Image");
                continue;
            }

            var image = document.createElement("img");
            var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
            image.file = file;
            thumbnail.appendChild(image)

            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = (function (aImg) {
                return function (e) {
                    aImg.src = e.target.result;
                };
            }(image))
            var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            image.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(image, 100, 100)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This may be a strange question. Do you use update anywhere in your database? It sounds like you are overwriting your previous images if you select them one by one.

Comment: The images only get saved after they have been selected, so you can either select all of them at once, then click save or you can do it one by one until you have all the images you want then click save. Only when you select them all of them in one file browser session does it save all of them, if you select one by one it only save the last photo that was selected.

Comment: @Lunchbox sorry forgot to tag, so I need to do a temp store of some sort but how, also i dont really know Jquery much at all

Comment: Well, check where your array gets cleared, Create an top level array and then just push your image values into it each time you select an image. Then when the user clicks save, and the images are saved successfully, just clear your array then. You can have a look at this link to check where to define your array etc. Hope it helps - http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/scope/

Comment: Hey man had a look, cant get it right do you think you can maybe give it a shot? @Lunchbox

Comment: Sure, I'll write up an example of what I mean. What libraries are you using?

Comment: Thanks man! This is just using jquery-1.2.6.min.js I think @Lunchbox